# Draft option with adjustbox package

Tags: graphics, draft, adjustbox

I've been using the great labour-saving `adjustbox` package to excellent results. Nonetheless, when using the `draft` option with the `\adjustimage` command I do not get the expected result, namely, the same as with the earlier `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package. What I get is simply the file I'm giving to the command as its second argument, instead of the framed bounding box and the file name within it.

My command has the form

```
\adjustimage{draft}{mypicture.pdf}
```

Maybe it's just me doing something wrong or misunderstanding the way the option is to be issued, or something else... but

```
\includegraphics[draft]{mypicture.pdf}
```

works fine on the same file.

Anyone else gets the same result? Any suggestions?

EDIT:

If I issue the "compound" command

```
\adjustbox{}{\includegraphics[draft]{pic.pdf}}
```

it works as expected, but in the package documentation it is said (p. 3) that `\adjustimage` is defined precisely in terms of that "composition" -- if I didn't get the message wrong.

EDIT 2:

The "way out" above is actually far from satisfying because the file name will be resized according to the `\adjustbox` keys (empty in my example, but not so generally). I have tried with

```
\adjustbox{phantom,frame}{pic.pdf}
```

and it works fine, but of course I don't get the file name in the framed bounding box. So my question is now twofold: 1) How to get the non-resized file name inside the box?, and 2) How to get the proper behavior that I was expecting originally?

Comment: [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) does not provide a `draft` key-value option.

Comment: @Werner Yes, but `\adjustimage` should accept all legal options to `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @Werner: As egreg just said, that's it... and that's the point of my EDIT in my original post.

Comment: I'm the `adjustbox` author. Unfortunatly there is still some key combinations with `\adjustimage` which do not give the exact same result as with `\includegraphics`. It's on my ToDo list.

Comment: Please report any such issues with my packages directly to me. Bug reports don't make good SE question in my opinion, see [Questions which are bug reports](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2622).  My email address is mentioned in the manual and there is a bug tracker at http://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/adjustbox (for other packages see http://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/).

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Thanks so much for your attention. I was not sure that it was a bug rather than something being misunderstood on my part. Even with that bug, let me say that this is another great package from you and that it has proved very helpful in my work. Just one suggestion in regards to my SE question: maybe you could post your comments as an answer so that I could check it as the accepted one.